# Image has height and width of 0px

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am building an Angular 2 app with this [Angular 2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter).

When I run it locally everything works well. When I build it and run it deployed some of the images do not show up because their `height` and `width` become `0px` for some reason.

Then, when I refresh the page, all of the images show up fine.

If I then go and clear the cookies, on the first load of the page I have the same images problem again.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

An example image I have is:

```
<img class="img-responsive review-growth-img" src="assets/img/proj-5-years.png">
```

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs no we do not.  Would that make it not show up the first time if we did?

Comment: You could look at the Network tab in your browser's developer tools and see if the requests are being made the first time.

Comment: That's a relative path for that image.  Is it possible that navigating on your site results in that path being calculated to point to a different location? What happens if you use an absolute path (e.g. one beginning with `/`)?  Also, do you get an error in your browser's javascript console?

Comment: thanks everyone, I have determined that the problem is that it is taking the calls to get the images 3+ minutes to get a response, that is why they do not appear for a while the first time (then after being cached they appear quickly every time after that), so I am in the process of figuring that out.  I believe it is an environment issue because the images are fine on our dev site and locally but not our QA site.  If anyone has come across this before or knows a solution I would love to hear it.  Thanks